# java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Operation must use an updateable query

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc

```
SEVERE: null
```

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]
>   Operation must use an updateable query.   at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)     at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)  at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3109)  at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:337)
>     at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:287)

```
 public Student_Registration() {
    super("");
    initComponents();

    try {
        //DriverManager.registerDriver(new sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver());
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:student");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Check connectivity with database", "Error", 3);
    }


}
```

//Insert data to Db

```
 String insertinfo = "insert into student_info(name,dob,address,ten,twelve,sex,mail,mobile) values('" + txt_name.getText().toString() + "', '" + txt_dob.getText().toString() + "', '" + txt_add.getText().toString() + "', '" + txt_10.getText().toString() + "','" + txt_12.getText().toString() + "','" + cb_sex.getSelectedItem().toString() + "','" + txt_mail.getText().toString() + "','" + txt_mobile.getText().toString() + "')";


    try {
        Statement ist = con.createStatement();
        ist.executeUpdate(insertinfo);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {

        Logger.getLogger(Student_Registration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        System.out.printf("" + insertinfo);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is just a file permission issue occuring with ODBC data sources.

MS says ;

> This problem occurs if you try to edit a worksheet that is saved or
>   opened as ReadOnly.

NOTE: ReadOnly is the default setting for an ODBC connection to Excel, with or without a data source name (DSN). Therefore, the user must always change that setting to edit data.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316475

You may check for read-only attribute in both db file and DSN settings.

**To resolve this problem, use the following aproach:**

- Make sure that the LockType property of the Recordset object is not
  set to ReadOnly.
- Make sure that the file that you are trying to open
- If you are connecting through a DSN, follow these steps:

  - Open Control Panel, and then click ODBC Data Source Administrator.
  - Double-click your DSN.
  - In the ODBC Microsoft Excel Setup dialog box, click Options.
  - Make sure that the ReadOnly check box is not selected.